# Where do I ask a question about the Facebook Android app?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'd like to turn off Facebook chat (appear offline) in Facebook's Android app.

I am not quite sure where to post question. On what site within the network would it be on topic?

PS: I was wondering if we have something similar to "Super User" which is where we usually get solution for computer related issues.

Comment: Reading your question again, are you simply asking on which site to ask? Because I can't tell. Are you aware of [android.SE]?

Comment: Questions about the relevant site(s) to post a question on should be tagged `[site-rec]`.

Comment: @misguided, [su] is part of the Stack Exchange network, so we do have something like it, yes.

Comment: @slhck: from what I make of it, you've interpreted the question correctly.  He's asking "what site on the Stack Exchange network would this question be on-topic in?".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by a look at [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) [on-topic list](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I think your question would be fine there.

> Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange is for enthusiasts, power users, and regular people who use the Android operating system.
>
> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using your Android device
> - **Using a particular app on your Android device**
> - Trying to solve an error or other issue in using your Android device

Your question falls under the emphasised category. If you are still unsure, ask on [Android Enthusiasts Meta](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Yep, this is okay there.